# How to use select_related with Django create()?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # some fields

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeginKey(Parent)
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    # other fields
```

I have a function like this:

```
1. def some_function(unique_id):
2.     parent_object = Parent.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id)
3.     new_child = Child.objects.create(name='Joe', parent=parent_object)
4.     call_some_func(new_child.parent.name, new_child.species.name)
```

In the line 4, a db query is generated for `Species`. Is there any way, I can use select_related to prefetch the `Species`, so as to prevent extra query.

Can it be done while I use `.create()`. This is just an example , I am using many other fields too and they are querying the DB every time.

The only way I can think is after line 3 using this code:

```
child_obj = Child.objects.select_related('species').get(id=new_child.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only parameter that `create` accepts is `force_insert` which is not related to what you're asking, so it seems it's not possible. Also, noticing that `create` performs an `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` statement, I don't think it would be possible anyway because you cannot return columns from other tables.

Possibly the best approach is what you already suggested: do a `get()` afterwards with the related fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the select_related to the object after created. Nevertheless in the example you give it could have the same amount of queries.